# Should I place a comma before “and” after listing 2 items

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, commas, present-tense

Like for example, “ Can I get a Glazed donut, and a cake pop “ or “ Do you guys have French fries, chicken nuggets, and burgers?

I keep getting confused because when I put “and” it feels like I don’t need a comma.